# Video gets freeze at the end when playing in iPhone 4s

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have one countdown video to be played before quiz which is kept in bundle. The Video gets played properly in iPhone 6 [iOS 11.2] and quiz starts, but when I run the app in iPhone 4s [iOS 9.3] the video starts with a slight delay and at the end of video, the screen gets freeze for sometime and then the Quiz starts.

```
 func playVideo()
{

    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "countDown", ofType:"mp4") else {
        debugPrint("Video not found")
        return
    }
    let item = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))

    player = AVPlayer.init(playerItem: item)

    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = self.viewVideo.bounds

    player?.volume = 0
    self.viewVideo.isHidden = false

    player?.play()

    self.viewVideo.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

    let resetPlayer =  {

        self.player?.pause()
        self.viewVideo.isHidden = true

        // Moves to quiz
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toFinalQuiz", sender: self)


    }
    playerObserver = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player?.currentItem, queue: nil) {
        notification in
        resetPlayer()

    }


}
```

Comment: providing the code which you have used to play the video and then it's transition to the quiz at the end, will help in understand this issue better

Comment: Plz post your try, code

Comment: @CoderFrom94 Plz check, I have added the code.

Comment: @SPatel Plz check, I have added the code

Comment: I think the issue is that, There is a delay in performing Segue in iPhone 4

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line after the comment,

```
// Moves to quiz
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toFinalQuiz", sender: self)
}
```

Let me know if this doesn't work...

For the delay at the start, I'd recommend to keep the video loaded and ready to play beforehand. So that you can being playing the video using just `player?.play()` when you need it.

Comment: Ok, Let me check and I'll let you know.